# ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'sklearn.preprocessing._encoders.OneHotEncoder'>

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

X_train and y_train were different dtypes.
Stumbled upon this error while using Onehotencoder to convert dtype.
trying to use asarray() but can find my way through it

Here's the code  :

```
X_train, X_test , y_train , y_test  = train_test_split(data, labels ,test_size = 0.3, random_state  = 1 )
print(X_train.shape , y_train.shape , X_test.shape , y_test.shape)

y_train = OneHotEncoder(y_train , dtype = 'float64')

epochs = 15 
Net = model.fit(X_train , y_train , batch_size = 32 , epochs = epochs , validation_data = (X_test , y_test))
```

Here's the error :

```
 ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-13-59f0001da0f5> in <module>
  1 epochs = 15
  ----> 2 Net = model.fit(X_train , y_train , batch_size = 32 , epochs = epochs ,        validation_data = (X_test , y_test))

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in       _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
   106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
   107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   --> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
   109 
   110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

  ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in     fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle,    class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,       validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1047          training_utils.RespectCompiledTrainableState(self):
   1048       # Creates a `tf.data.Dataset` and handles batch and epoch iteration.
   -> 1049       data_handler = data_adapter.DataHandler(
   1050           x=x,
   1051           y=y,

  ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model, steps_per_execution)
   1102       self._steps_per_execution_value = steps_per_execution.numpy().item()
   1103 
   -> 1104     adapter_cls = select_data_adapter(x, y)
   1105     self._adapter = adapter_cls(
   1106         x,

   ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in select_data_adapter(x, y)
    966   if not adapter_cls:
    967     # TODO(scottzhu): This should be a less implementation-specific error.
     --> 968     raise ValueError(
     969         "Failed to find data adapter that can handle "
     970         "input: {}, {}".format(

 ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'sklearn.preprocessing._encoders.OneHotEncoder'>
```

​ '''

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from how you used OneHotEncoder. Your neural network needs 2 objects that are tensors, but OneHotEncoder is another type of object that is used to change the tensors.
According to the documentation of sklearn:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

You can see that you first need to instantiate the object OneHotEncoder and next use the .fit() function to switch the digits to the one-hot encoding.

Also, **your code does not encode the y_test** as one hot. The best approach is to convert the labels before the train_test_split function.

```
#Create the instance object and directly fit the labels
labels = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore').fit(labels)

X_train, X_test , y_train , y_test  = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size = 0.3, random_state  = 1 )
print(X_train.shape , y_train.shape , X_test.shape , y_test.shape)

epochs = 15 
Net = model.fit(X_train , y_train , batch_size = 32 , epochs = epochs , validation_data = (X_test , y_test))
```

Comment: My train and test arrays are singleton arrays, it throws me this error : TypeError: Singleton array array(OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection.

Comment: According to your suggestion , I updated the code as : 
X_train, X_test , y_train , y_test  = train_test_split(data, labels ,test_size = 0.3, random_state  = 1 )
print(X_train.shape , y_train.shape , X_test.shape , y_test.shape)
labels = np.reshape(labels, (-1,2))
labels = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore').fit(labels)